# How do I require a module in LUA wasm?

Tags: module, lua, virtual-machine, webassembly

recently I've came across this:
https://github.com/vvanders/wasm_lua

It works perfectly fine, but when I try to require a module in it it outputs an error saying that this module isn't there, even though I put it in the main directory of the page.

I've tried putting the module in every single folder of this, but it seems that Lua is running somewhere out of this folder.

How do I solve this issue? Where Lua runs, if it's not running in the main site directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua WASM is a way to run Lua by the browser, but it uses Lua within the system itself to perform the tasks, which means browser runs only the Front End (HTML for example)

see that when you try to import a library, it gives an error and shows a directory on the website system where it looks for the library (honestly the risk of hacking the website server is really huge that way)

You can even import a library, but for that you need to have lua WASM installed on your own computer, run it on your own server, and then have the library you want inside the folder where lua WASM looks for. That way, Lua WASM will search for the library on YOUR computer, not on the computer on the site where Lua WASM is hosted

Comment: Huh, that totally makes sense now. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Is there a way to ommit this? I mean, something else reading the content of file `module.lua` in JS/C and then passing it to luaL_dostring()?

Comment: fortunately and unfortunately Lua WASM does not allow working with functions that handle processes like os.execute and io.popen. These could make the system's document handler easier, but it would be easily hacked.

There is also no way to import libraries like "LuaSocket" too to work with parts of the system, so I think there is no way to do this manually

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the answer I needed.